# jquery minus multiplication

Tags: jquery, html, math

Im creating a very simple till system, and adding items seems to work very well, but when it comes to removing an item from the order, it doesnt quite work out.

Got my code loaded up here http://jsfiddle.net/Unjustified/sVX2x/

once Ive added a few options, then remove the first item, it will set the total to 0, and minus the value * the order in which I originally added them. i.e.

```
    item 1 = £2
    item 2 = £3
    item 3 = £4

    Total = £9
```

Then remove item 2 and the total should be £6 but instead is £3 (item value multiplied by position in list)

if anyone has any ideas, I would be very greatful, Thanks!

Comment: You're adding multiple event handlers on the same class. The quickest way to fix this is to change it to a delegated event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/sVX2x/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your click event handler for the remove logic nested in the click handler for adding. It should be separate.

Also, since you are dynamically adding and removing elements in the list of purchases, you need to use `on()` ([API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) to capture changes in the DOM.

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gx8PK/

Comment: 100% agree. Use the on syntax.

http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data

What this does it binds an event to every single item-listed class inside the document, even ones that haven't been created yet. This way you don't have to create events every time an element is created.